# Want to grep a specfic word in the line and add one new line below that line in a File

Tags: linux, bash

I want to grep the specific word only in the object Host line ( linux.google.com ) and add the new line below that object host line.
    Display name = "A: Linux.google.com"

```
object Host "linux.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]
}

object Host "kali.google.com" {
import "linux"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = [linux ]
}

object Host "windows.google.com" {
import "linux"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["windows" ]
}

object Host "os.google.com" {
import "windows"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]
}
```

I am searching for linux.google.com

If the string found in the Object Host line then I want to enter new line ( Display name "A: Linux.google.com" )   ( Display name "B: os.google.com" ) as mentioned below.

```
object Host "linux.google.com" {
Display name "A: Linux.google.com"
import "windows"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]
}

object Host "os.google.com" {
Display name "B: os.google.com"
import "windows"
address = "linux.google.com"
groups = ["linux"]
}
```

But only search the string in the Object Host Line, not in any other line

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one line in `sed`:

```
> sed -i '/object Host "linux.google.com"/a Display name "A: Linux.google.com"' input.txt
```

How it works:

- The -i option tells `sed` to modify the file in-place (e.g., rather than you having to make a temp copy, then overwrite the original with the temp copy)
- The `/object Host "linux.google.com"/` is a `sed` [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html). It tells `sed` which line(s) to operate on. In this case, it's a regular expression. But `sed` has multiple forms of addresses, including line numbers, ranges of line numbers, etc.
- The `a` after the address regex is the `sed` [append](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) command. Whatever you put after the `a` is appended on the line below the one matched by the address.

Comment: Kindly have a look at the above code I had edited and give us the suggestion for the requirement @Mike Holt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with sed. However, we can do the following.
Let `input` be the name of your file and `output` be an output file.

```sh
while IFS= read -r var; do 
  echo "$var"; 
  if [[ $var == *"Host \"linux.google.com\""* ]]; then 
    echo "Display name \"A: Linux.google.com\""; 
  fi; 
done < input > output
```

The code is very simple. It reads your file line per line and verifies if the line has the keyword you want to match. If true, then it prints what you desire in the line below.